# How to change Jax-WS WSDL @IDREF binding

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, spring-ws, jax-ws-customization

I'm sucessfully exposing a contract-first JAX-WS web service on a Tomcat servlet container with Jax-WS [Spring support](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/). I'm having troulbes with `xs:idref` types though. The original XSD file contains a complex type

```
  <xs:complexType name="DocumentScopeOptionalTypeReferenceIdentifier">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="DocumentScopeReferenceIdentifierContent">
         ...
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="DocumentScopeReferenceIdentifierContent">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:IDREF">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

which xjc correctly compiles to

```
public class DocumentScopeOptionalTypeReferenceIdentifier {

  @XmlValue
  @XmlIDREF
  protected Object value;

  ...
}
```

When I deploy the webservice, however, the `@XmlIDREF` annotation gets ignored and I end up with an `xs:anyType` in the namespace declaration of the resulting WSDL

```
<xs:complexType name="DocumentScopeOptionalRoleReferenceIdentifier">
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
...
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Clients of the webservice in question report, that they cannot generate Client stubs (using C#) with this `anyType` present. How would I change that back to `xs:idref`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess my approach was a little bit too naiv. After doing a bit of research I came to the conclusion that customizing the generated WSDL is not possible. I now switched to a contract first approach and specify a hand-crafted WSDL file manually.

I've read that any WSDL file located under META-INF/wsdl should be picked up automatically by JAX-WS, if it contains a corresponding service and port name. This didn't work for me, so I had to specify the WSDL file explicitely using the `wsdlLocation` attribute on the `@WebService` annotation

```
@WebService(
   targetNamespace = "...", 
   serviceName = "...", 
   portName = "...", 
   wsdlLocation = "/META-INF/wsdl/mywebservice.wsdl"
)
public class MyWebService { ... }
```

Deploying the webservice on Tomcat was straight forward following the instructions on the [Jax-WS community page](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/)